# Concurrent access of a row (in a database table) by java program?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I have a table with some rows in my database. In my Java program, there is a "Consumer class" which uses a row and a "Producer Class" which puts data into this row. How do I ensure that the producer cannot alter the row unless it gets permission from the consumer ?

My database is SQL Server 2008 r2.

Comment: *Very low quality:* What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: @DannyBeckett - I have not tried anything yet. But, I need some suggestions on how to to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure really understand your question.

You probably can put a flag column in this row, only when Consumer class update the flag, means give permission to Producer to update it.

Comment: If you just ask about concurrent issue, then I can tell you if you only have Consumer Class and Producer Class to access to this row, and producer update this row and Consumer read this row, then there is no concurrent issue. SQL server default is read commit, and every time when Producer update the row, it will put a update lock.

Comment: The Consumer loads row data into memory to use that data for some time. After that, it does not touch the row. After loading by consumer, the Producer is free to edit the row. But, I don't want producer to edit the row until the consumer finishes using that row.